# 2nd Order Differential Equation ElectroMagnetics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wave-equation

I am trying to solve the 2nd differential equation shown in the picture.

[image]

I do not understand how the general solution has been formulated with cosine ore sine. Could any one please help? Thanks

Comment: the simplest way to check is to just substitute the proposed solution back into (3) and verify that it works

Comment: but how would i get to that solution tho? @peek-a-boo can't find a way

Answer (score 0):

The given differential equation is a linear homogeneous constant-coefficient differential equation. Solutions to $ax’’+bx’+cx=0$ are found by obtaining the roots of the characteristic polynomial $ar^2+br+c=0$. Let $r_1$ and $r_2$ be the roots of this polynomial, then the solution to the differential equation is $x=c_1e^{r_1t}+c_2e^{r_2t}$. If your roots are complex, then using Euler’s formula $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$ you can transform the complex exponentials into sines and cosines.

Comment: The thing is I do not believe that my roots are complex. Like I found the roots and I do not obtain complex root.

Comment: @nachofest If $k_z^2>0$ you will have complex roots. If not then you are correct and the solution can be written in terms of exponentials and not sines and cosines