# Examples of 2nd Order Differential Equations in Electromagnetism

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, electromagnetism

I am looking for examples of second-order ODE's that are similar to the spring, and pendulum, as well as the LRC, LC, RC, and LR circuits and involve electromagnetism. I know how to solve them, and I am just searching for some in my Physics textbook and didn't find any besides the LRC, and etc.
\begin{align}mx''+kx&=0\ \text{spring} \\ L\theta''+g\sin(\theta)&=0 \ \text{pendulum} \\ LQ''+\frac{Q}C&=0 \ \text{Inductor Capacitor} \\ LQ''+RQ'+\frac{Q}C&=0 \ \text{Inductor Resistor Capacitor}\end{align}

### Edit

I did try a search its just I found many PDEs instead.

Comment: Why a close vote, is there a reason why?

Comment: What about https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3255681/2nd-order-differential-equation-electromagnetics

Comment: How about the [telegrapher's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations#Sinusoidal_steady-state)?